# Can I use part of a Shell Object parsing name in the windows portable device (WPD) api to get a file stream?

Tags: c#, winapi, usb

Is it always valid to use the first part of the last guid from a windows api codepack ShellObject parsing name representing a path to a USB-connected android or iphone device when transferring a file to local storage in the windows portable device (WPD) api?

Eg. an example parsing name from a ShellObject get parsing name call:

```
::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}\\\?\usb#vid_22b8&pid_2e82#zy322kldjb#{6ac27878-a6fa-4155-ba85-f98f491d4f33}\{00000009-0001-0001-0000-000000000000}\{00000009-0001-0001-0000-000000000000}\{00005461-0001-0001-0000-000000000000}
```

As far as I can tell, this represents:

```
- My Computer    ::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}\
- USB device     \\?\usb#vid_22b8&pid_2e82#zy322kldjb#{6ac27878-a6fa-4155-ba85-f98f491d4f33}\
- Root folder    SID-{10001,,26401026048}\
- Folder 1       {00000009-0001-0001-0000-000000000000}\
- Folder 2       {00000075-0001-0001-0000-000000000000}\
- File           {00005461-0001-0001-0000-000000000000}
```

Enumerating the contents of `Folder 2` on the device using the WPD api, I can see the same file has a file id like `o5461` - this looks like part of the `File` part above.

Is this assumption always correct - can I always use it like in the following code, to copy one file from an android phone to local storage on the c-drive? Or is there sometimes a mismatch? Also, what does the "o" mean in the file id?

This seems to work, but I'm hesitant to use it in production-ready code.

```
using System.IO;
using PortableDeviceApiLib;

public class Copier
{
  public void PerformCopy()
  {
    var deviceId = @"\\?\usb#vid_22b8&pid_2e82#zy322kldjb#{6ac27878-a6fa-4155-ba85-f98f491d4f33}";
    var sourceItemGuidString = "{00005461-0001-0001-0000-000000000000}";
    var destinationPath = @"C:\Test\";
    var fileName = "Testing.jpg";
    var size = 3738545;

    // get "o5461" from the parsing path from the Shell libraries
    var fileId = "o" + sourceItemGuidString.Replace("{", string.Empty).Replace("}", string.Empty).Split('-')[0].TrimStart('0');

    this.TransferContentFromDevice(deviceId, fileId, size, destinationPath, fileName);
  }

  private void TransferContentFromDevice(string deviceId, string fileId, long length, string saveToPath, string fileName)
  {
    PortableDeviceClass device;

    try
    {
      device = SomehowGetOnePortableDeviceAndConnectToIt(deviceId);

      // Make sure that the target dir exists.
      Directory.CreateDirectory(saveToPath);

      device.Content(out var content);
      content.Transfer(out var resources);

      var property = new _tagpropertykey
      {
        fmtid = new Guid(0xE81E79BE, 0x34F0, 0x41BF, 0xB5, 0x3F, 0xF1, 0xA0, 0x6A, 0xE8, 0x78, 0x42),
        pid = 0
      };

      uint optimalTransferSize = 0;
      resources.GetStream(fileId, ref property, 0, ref optimalTransferSize, out IStream wpdStream);

      var sourceStream = (System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IStream)wpdStream;
      using (var targetStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(saveToPath, fileName), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
      {
        // Get the total size.
        long written = 0;
        long lPCt = 0;
        unsafe
        {
          var buffer = new byte[1024];
          int bytesRead;
          do
          {
            sourceStream.Read(buffer, 1024, new IntPtr(&bytesRead));
            targetStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

            written += 1024;
            long PCt = length > 0 ? (100 * written) / length : 100;
            if (PCt != lPCt)
            {
              lPCt = PCt;
              Console.WriteLine("Progress: " + lPCt);
            }
          } while (bytesRead > 0);
        }
      }          
    }
    finally
    {
      Disconnect(device);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You're supposed to call EnumObjects to get object ids: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/portabledeviceapi/nf-portabledeviceapi-iportabledevicecontent-enumobjects PS: note the interop build by tooling for .NET is quite broken for WPD... it's difficult to use all API as you should be able to.

Comment: Or if you have a ShellObject representing the item under a device, you can just do `item.Properties.GetProperty(new PropertyKey(new Guid("{ef6b490d-5cd8-437a-affc-da8b60ee4a3c}"), 23))` to get this objectid. This property key is PKEY_GenericObj_StorageID or WPD_OBJECT_CONTAINER_FUNCTIONAL_OBJECT_ID

Comment: @SimonMourier is there any way to get a stream or bytes from the `ShellObject` itself, without going through WPD like this?

Comment: @meataxe Hard coded is not production-ready. You can refer to [WPD programming guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wpd_sdk/programming-guide) and [WpdApiSample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/wpd/wpdapisample/cpp) for how to transfer content to or from a portable device

Comment: Yes you can get a stream from the shell item. You have to use IShellItem::BindToHandler with BHID_Stream on the item. Unfortunately, I don't think this is accessible using the WindowsAPICodePack which misses a lot of thing.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT I can barely read c++, and translating it back into usable c# is beyond me, I'm afraid, so while I appreciate your taking the time to comment, I'm not able to use the information in those links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `item` has a parsing name like below, I was after the `5461` part from the final guid:

```
::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}\\\?\usb#vid_22b8&pid_2e82#zy322kldjb#{6ac27878-a6fa-4155-ba85-f98f491d4f33}\SID-{10001,,26401026048}\{00000009-0001-0001-0000-000000000000}\{00000075-0001-0001-0000-000000000000}\{00005461-0001-0001-0000-000000000000}
```

We can use the following code which will get the `WPD_OBJECT_ID` property from a `ShellObject`. More info on this and related properties [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wpd_sdk/object-properties):

```
string GetFileId(ShellObject item)
{
  const int WPD_OBJECT_ID = 2;      
  var property = item.Properties.GetProperty(new PropertyKey(new Guid("{ef6b490d-5cd8-437a-affc-da8b60ee4a3c}"), WPD_OBJECT_ID));
  return property.ValueAsObject as string;
}
```

This returns the file id `o5641`, which can then be used in my `TransferContentFromDevice` method directly.

Thanks to @SimonMourier for pointing me in the right direction.